# Help with difficult uniform convergence problem.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Define a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ on $[0,1]$ by

$$
f_n(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{n} & \quad \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}< x \leq \frac{1}{2^n} \\
            0 & \quad \text{elsewhere}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$, but  that the Weirstrass M-Test fails.

My attempt:

I've noticed that $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{1} & \quad \frac{1}{2^{2}}< x < \frac{1}{2} \\
            \frac{1}{2} & \quad \frac{1}{2^{3}}< x < \frac{1}{2^2}\\
              \frac {1}{3} & \quad \frac{1}{2^{4 }}< x < \frac{1}{2^3}\\
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

so I said $|S_n(x) - S_m(x)| = |\sum_{k={m+1}}^n f_k(x)| = \frac{1}{k} $ for some k with $m+ 1 \leq k \leq n$

Then $|\sum_{k={m+1}}^n f_k(x) = \frac{1}{k} < \frac{1}{m+1} < \epsilon$ if  $m+ 1 < \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ or $ m > \frac{1}{\epsilon} -1$

Therefore for $\epsilon > 0, \ \ $ choose m to be a positive integer $> \frac{1}{\epsilon} -1$ then it satisties the cauchy criterion.

Does anyone have a better way to do this proof or can fix any errors I have made.

Comment: The proof is correct in showing that the Cauchy criterion is satisfied uniformly.  Just use a partial sum difference $|S_{n}(x) - S_{m}(x)|$ rather than $|f_{n}(x) - f_{m}(x)|$ in your notation.